# Excel VBA code to get link and click it

Tags: excel, vba

This is a screenshot of a link which I want VBA Excel to click:

[image: link which i want VBA excel to click]

I am using this code in VBA Excel after navigating to the required page but it's not getting that link which I have shown above in the picture.

```
set Alllinks=objIE.document.getallelementsbytagname("a")

For Each link In Alllinks

    'MsgBox link.innertext & " - " & link.href

    If InStr(link.innerText, "ABERCROMBIE JOE R") > 0 Then
        link.Click

    Exit For

    End If

Next link
```

Comment: Have you checked by using alert, whether the link comes or not?

Comment: I know the reason but dont know how to modify code the link is htm

Comment: yes only html links comes not htm

Comment: http://www.deltacomputersystems.com/cgi-lra2/LRMCGI01?HTMCNTY=AL39&HTMBASE=C&HTMSEARCH=BEGIN&HTMNAME=ABERCROMBIE+JOE+R&HTMADDRNUMBER=&HTMADDRSTREET=&HTMPARCEL1=&HTMPARCEL2=&HTMPARCEL3=&HTMPARCEL4=&HTMPARCEL5=&HTMPARCEL6=&HTMPARCEL7=&HTMPARCEL8=&HTMPPIN=&HTMSUBMIT=Submit

Comment: this is the link of the web page i want to get the very first link   "ABERCROMBIE JOE R  "

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
Dim httpObject As Object
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Dim links As Variant

With httpObject
    .Open "GET", "http://www.deltacomputersystems.com/cgi-lra2/LRMCGI01?HTMCNTY=AL39&HTMBASE=C&HTMSEARCH=BEGIN&HTMNAME=ABERCROMBIE+JOE+R&HTMADDRNUMBER=&HTMADDRSTREET=&HTMPARCEL1=&HTMPARCEL2=&HTMPARCEL3=&HTMPARCEL4=&HTMPARCEL5=&HTMPARCEL6=&HTMPARCEL7=&HTMPARCEL8=&HTMPPIN=&HTMSUBMIT=Submit", False
    .send
    Do Until httpObject.ReadyState = 4
    Loop
    doc.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    Set links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    MsgBox (links(0).href)

End With
```

Here is the output

[image: output]